# Recommended server for continuous integration for a PHP project

Tags: php, continuous-integration

I'm working on a PHP project and I would like to know recommendations for implementing [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

I've read all the theory, but I never got to use continuous integration. So it should be rather easy to start.

I've read about [Xinc](http://code.google.com/p/xinc/), [Hudson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29), among others, but I would like to get some feedback based on experience. Have you used continuous integration in PHP projects? What has been your experience? Which server would you recommend?

Comment: you can also use [fazend.com](http://www.fazend.com) - hosted CI service

Comment: There's a pretty similar question regarding hosted (so you don't have to setup/maintain your own server) continuous integration services. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755268/hosted-continuous-integration-for-php/12767571

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have had good luck with [phpUnderControl](http://phpundercontrol.org/about.html), which is based on CruiseControl.

Comment: @Petah: the whole project appears to be dead.  I don't seem to be able to delete the answer since it is the accepted one.

Answer (score 17):

There is also Jenkins now that [Oracle made a fuss about Hudson](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/01/jenkins). There is a config template for it that makes it ridiculously easy to setup with all the [QA Tools](http://phpqatools.org/) you'd need for a PHP CI environment:

- http://edorian.github.io/2011-02-01-setting-up-jenkins-for-php-projects
- http://jenkins-php.org
- http://jenkins-ci.org

Comment: Link is dead on the edorian blog :(

Comment: @Tek fixed. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried CruiseControl with phpUnderControl and Hudson. I also had a look at Xinc, but it seems to be too limited at the moment.

I went with Hudson in the end, because it is a lot easier to set up than CruiseControl and works well with either ant scripts or simple bash scripts.

Another option which looks promising is [arbit](http://arbitracker.org/). It is a bit like trac, but adds CI. There is also something by the Symfony guys, but it is at a very early stage.