# Continous integration tool for symfony project

Tags: php, symfony1, continuous-integration

I have to set up continous integration for php. My CI server should be able to build the project, run the unit tests and create a report with the result. What would be the best continuos integration tool for a symfony project? I can't decide between phpUnderControl + CruiseCotrol, Xinc, or Hudson.

Comment: add [Arbit](http://arbitracker.org/news.html) to that list and please tell us what you are looking for in a CI server, otherwise [you will likely have people tell you which CI server they like best](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941537/recommended-server-for-continuous-integration-for-php-project) (which makes your question subjective and a duplicate)

Comment: All of the ones you mention, as well as Arbit which Gordon mentions, should be able to handle CI with Symfony projects - as Gordon says, you need to define your requirements more specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Opinion:

- Xinc is to old und not supported are activly developed any more.
- Hudson: Has everything you need for integrating symfony projects. I have a Hudson-Server that integrates several Symfony projects. There is everything available as plugins. Unit-Testing, Code-Coverage, Statical code analyses and other things. Hudson has a nice and easy to use webbased Administration console.
- phpUnderControl: Nice for PHP Projects. But I don't like the administration and found i trickier to get some projects integrated with it

  - Arbit: A nice new choice. I have not tested it for Symfony-Projects so far. Because it is new it doesn't have the amount of configuration features or plugins as Hudson has.

I like Hudson the most.