# Can you advise me a good continuous integration tool for PHP and tell me why?

Tags: php, deployment, continuous-integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended server for Continuous Integration for PHP Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941537/recommended-server-for-continuous-integration-for-php-project)

Hi,

I'd like to try Continuous Integration. I'm mostly writing PHP application with Zend Framework  to be deployed on linux server.

I took a look to Hudson, Phing, Ant, but all of these tools looks like at the mean time doing the same thing and not.

Do you have any feedback and good tutorials to start things?

Most wanted feature would be the ability to check PHPUnit test, change SetEnv setting in .htaccess file, runs somes scripts, adjust rewrite url settings (i'm using vhost locally), statistics, notifications, and others feature you think essentials.

Comment: Highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects

Answer (score 5):

Hudson got renamed, to Jenkins - not much more has changed with the code iteself, but there has been something of a rush of new projects around it.

In the PHP space, there are a couple to make it easier to setup and use though - [jenkins-php.org](http://jenkins-php.org/), similarly, there is [php project wizard](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-project-wizard) which even further automates new projects within the structure of jenkins-php.

Phing and Ant are automation tools, you write XML with various commands and it acts upon them.

Most of the feature you are looking for are best dealt with by various different means.

- Run PHPUnit test - Jenkins, with the tools within it, as setup by jenkins-php, and with the actual project created with PPW.
- change .htaccess file - depending what yo are doing there, you may be able to setup your local development environment to avoid having different code. I try to keep changes only in the configuration .ini file - maybe a switch based on the local manchine hostname, or a SetEnv in the apache Vhost.
- A number of the rest could be done by a deployment tool, like Capistrano. I've used it to deploy a couple of PHP-based sites and the relevant plug-ins to remove rails-ish behaviour and use more usual PHP setup are easy to install. http://capify.org has details of them