# Hosted Continuous Integration for PHP?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, jenkins

I just wanted to check if anyone knows any hosted continous integration services made for web-based projects using PHP ?

I have been searching around but most are made for Java, Ruby and some for iOS/Android. I am reverting to having to set up my own CI server with Jenkin. I am guess there is not enough demand for CI on the PHP side to justify hosted services to support it off the shelf.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941537/recommended-server-for-continuous-integration-for-a-php-project

Comment: https://travis-ci.org/ would work if your project is open source.

Comment: Thanks, that question was for software primarily. I was looking for a hosted service. Travis would be a great option but my projects are closed source at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a list of hosted continuous integration providers on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Travis-CI/What-are-the-alternatives-to-Travis-CI-Are-there-any-alternative-hosted-CI-services-for-open-source-projects/answer/Moritz-Plassnig).

Some of them also support PHP:

- circleci.com
- drone.io
- codeship.io (disclaimer: I'm one of the cofounders)
- travis-ci.org

Answer (score 4):

[CircleCi](https://circleci.com) supports most web apps, and we have a lot of users who use PHP. You'll have to supply your own test commands, but you should be able to set it up in a few minutes, and all the databases and libraries you need should be available.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this review of all existing continuous integration hosted services: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/10/05/ten-hosted-continuous-integration-services.html